# android can't make httppost inside facebook api call

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-asynctask

I am trying to make a HTTP POST inside the Facebook Graph API call. Here is my code. The code is working when I call the function `executeHTTP()` outside the Facebook API call. If i placed the `executeHTTP()` inside the `onCompleted()` function of Facebook call then it shows URL not found error.

```
GraphRequest graphRequest = new GraphRequest(
        AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
        "/"+photoID,
        null,
        HttpMethod.GET,
        new GraphRequest.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //Log.d("Photo Response ","Response " + response);

                JSONObject json = response.getJSONObject();
                try{
                    //Log.d("Photo", json.getString("picture"));
                    // Store the photo id and url into the hashmap
                    photoURLS.put(json.getString("id"), json.getString("picture"));
                    noOfRequest--;

                    // HTTP Post
                    executeHTTP(); //****** THIS LINE
                }
                catch(JSONException e){
                    //
                    noOfRequest--;
                }
            }
        }
    );

    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putString("fields", "picture");
    graphRequest.setParameters(parameters);
    graphRequest.executeAsync();
```

I want to call the function `executeHTTP()` (which handles HTTP POST) after the completion of the Facebook call. Is it possible? If so, how? Have I missed anything in the code?

```
public void executeHTTP(){

        // execute http post here
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : photoURLS.entrySet()) {
            Log.d(entry.getKey() , entry.getValue());
        }

        // HTTP POST
        JSONObject data = new JSONObject(photoURLS); // convert the hashmap into json object
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("json",data.toString()));


// Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    String response = "";

    try {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://www.geoamy.com/uploadImages.php");
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.d("PHP", "POST Response >>> " + response);
}
```

Edit: This is what I'm getting. There is no error on log

```
09-02 19:30:28.500: D/PHP(374): POST Response >>> <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
09-02 19:30:28.500: D/PHP(374): <html><head>
09-02 19:30:28.500: D/PHP(374): <title>403 Forbidden</title>
09-02 19:30:28.500: D/PHP(374): </head><body>
09-02 19:30:28.500: D/PHP(374): <h1>Forbidden</h1>
09-02 19:30:28.500: D/PHP(374): <p>You don't have permission to access /uploadImages.php
09-02 19:30:28.500: D/PHP(374): on this server.</p>
09-02 19:30:28.500: D/PHP(374): <p>Additionally, a 404 Not Found
09-02 19:30:28.500: D/PHP(374): error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.</p>
09-02 19:30:28.500: D/PHP(374): </body></html>
```

Comment: show us the rest of your code, need to see the code for executeHTTP()

Comment: @DeanWild I updated the rest of the code

Comment: add the stack trace too

Comment: I added the response. I'm not getting any errors

Comment: You're misreading the response. You're getting a `403 Forbidden`, which means, just as it states, that you do not have permission to access the `uploadImages.php`. The 404 is only thrown because there's no error document for the 403 error. You need to authenticate to this "geoamy.com" server.

Comment: @323go good catch. But If I make the httppost outside the API call, then it works

Comment: i think your post request is malformed in some way, when you call executeHTTP() from outside the API call then photoURLS will have no data in so it just happens to work. When photoURLS DOES have some data in then your post request will looks very different and is causing issues

Comment: If so, I wont get 403 error